# JSON REST - ID in URI or JSON Body

Tags: php, rest, api, http

I am learning REST api (in php) and I have a question about where I should be putting the ID for the resource I want to update.

Do I put it in the URI and patch to /users/23 with body of:

```
{
    “name”: “John”
}
```

Or in the JSON body and patch to /users

```
{
    “id”: 23,
    “name”: “John”
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [Google Developer API design guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/), API's should be resource oriented. i.e. API path in itself should define all the relevant information about the resource path. Hence, putting the path in URI itself is the best practice

Comment: Thanks. So if I also wanted to patch multiple objects at the same time using the same http request would I patch to /users and then have an array in the json with the id as well as the updated data. So this would mean you could patch to both the single resource using /users/23 and /users? Or should the client always send multiple requests to patch resources?

Comment: @Michael if you must patch multiple resources in one request, consider using the url of the resource you are patching in the request body, instead of the id. The url == the id.